# How to access elements of grouped tibbles?

Tags: r, dplyr, tibble

I have rows with the first column corresponding to some ID and the other columns corresponding values. Each ID represents one observation of a person at a given time. A simplified code of mine looks like this:

```
library(tidyverse)

IDs <- c(1,1,2,2,3,3)
Values <- c(1.5,1.7,2.5,2.7,3.5,3.7)

y <- tibble(IDs,Values) %>% 
  group_by(IDs)
```

How can I access individual elements of the groups of the tibble *y* ? For example, say I want the second value of the second group, i.e. 2.7?

I want to do this to write a function that lets me check if the corresponding group to the ID has any 'NA's and then remove those IDs later on.

I appreciate any help.

EDIT:
First of all, thanks. The problem is that I do not want to drop every ID group who has a NA value but I want to basically look at each ID group which in my real example has 5 values corresponding to 5 observations. If the first 3 values ( corresponding to the first 3 observations ) has a NA, then I need to drop the whole ID group. Otherwise it can stay. That's why I suggested to access the individual elements so I can look at the first 3 for every group

Comment: This is two different questions. Accessing elements of specific groups is actually far more involved than determining if there are `NA` elements and then filtering out those IDs. For example the latter could be:
`IDs <- c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3)
Values <- c(1.5, 1.7, 2.5, NA, 3.5, 3.7)
y <- tibble(IDs, Values) %>%
group_by(IDs) %>%
mutate(hasNA = any(is.na(Values))) %>%
ungroup() %>%
filter(!hasNA) %>%
select(-hasNA)`

Comment: Thanks for the input. Please see my edit for clarification on why this approach doesn't work my real example

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. So in that csae you would just replace `any(is.na(Values))` with `all(is.na(Values[1:3])` if you want to remove the cases with the first 3 observations all being `NA`. For visual inspection you'd want to use `reframe`: `IDs <- c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3)
Values <- c(1.5,1.7,5.6,4.8,3.9,2.5,2.7,3.5,7.2,3.7,4.5)
y <- tibble(IDs,Values) %>% 
group_by(IDs) %>%
reframe(x = Values[1:3])`

Comment: This is amazing and exactly what I was looking for. Thank you. I'd mark this as the answer if you were to repost your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting my comment into an answer:

To facilitate visual inspection use `reframe`:

```r
IDs <- c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3)
Values <- c(1.5,1.7,5.6,4.8,3.9,2.5,2.7,3.5,7.2,3.7,4.5)

tibble(IDs, Values)
# A tibble: 11 x 2
#     IDs Values
#   <dbl>  <dbl>
# 1     1    1.5
# 2     1    1.7
# 3     1    5.6
# 4     1    4.8
# 5     1    3.9
# 6     2    2.5
# 7     2    2.7
# 8     2    3.5
# 9     3    7.2
# 10     3    3.7
# 11     3    4.5

y <- tibble(IDs,Values) %>% 
  group_by(IDs) %>%
  reframe(x = Values[1:3])

y

# A tibble: 9 x 2
#    IDs     x
#  <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     1   1.5
# 2     1   1.7
# 3     1   5.6
# 4     2   2.5
# 5     2   2.7
# 6     2   3.5
# 7     3   7.2
# 8     3   3.7
# 9     3   4.5
```

To filter out IDs where the first 3 values are `NA`:

```r
IDs <- c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3)
Values <- c(NA,NA,NA,4.8,3.9,2.5,2.7,3.5,7.2,3.7,4.5)

tibble(IDs,Values)
# A tibble: 11 x 2
#     IDs Values
#   <dbl>  <dbl>
# 1     1   NA  
# 2     1   NA  
# 3     1   NA  
# 4     1    4.8
# 5     1    3.9
# 6     2    2.5
# 7     2    2.7
# 8     2    3.5
# 9     3    7.2
# 10     3    3.7
# 11     3    4.5

y <- tibble(IDs,Values) %>% 
  group_by(IDs) %>%
  filter(!all(is.na(Values[1:3]))) %>%
  ungroup()

y

# A tibble: 6 x 2
#    IDs Values
#  <dbl>  <dbl>
# 1     2    2.5
# 2     2    2.7
# 3     2    3.5
# 4     3    7.2
# 5     3    3.7
# 6     3    4.5
```

Answer (score 1):

To filter for 2.7 by ID you could use

```
y <- tibble(IDs,Values) %>%
  group_by(IDs) %>%
  filter(any(Values == 2.7))
```

to do this for NA's you could use

```
y <- tibble(IDs,Values) %>%
  group_by(IDs) %>%
  filter(any(is.na(Values)))
```

To remove rows with NA's you could use drop_na from dplyr

```
y_drop_na <- y %>%
  drop_na(Values)
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. Please see my edit for clarification on why this approach doesn't work my real example